# Expressions for "exact copy"

Tags: phrases, expressions

Example:

> The painting was a [...] copy of the original.

Are there other common expressions other than *exact* and *identical*?

Comment: You can also say *perfect copy*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other words and phrases (from the top of my head)

Carbon copy
Duplicate
Clone (for persons)
Doppelgänger (also for persons)

Edit: sorry, most of these don't match your question. Perhaps only *'duplicate'*, but for other uses I will still keep them here.

Edit2:

> Duplicate
>
> 1. Identically copied from an original.

So the sentence would be

> The painting was a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, I might say that... As an artist, I may make a duplicate of my own work - say, on a better quality of paper.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try "a *facsimile* of the original".

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to say the painting was a **forgery**.

> **[Art forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_forgery)** is the creating and selling of works of art which are falsely credited to other, usually more famous, artists. Art forgery can be extremely lucrative, but modern dating and analysis techniques have made the identification of **forged** artwork much simpler.
>   <sub>Wikipedia</sub>

From the BBC, instructions on how to make *[forgeries](http://www.pewtersociety.org/collecting/fakes-forgeries-and-reproductions)*, *[fakes](http://www.pewtersociety.org/collecting/fakes-forgeries-and-reproductions)* and *[reproductions](http://www.pewtersociety.org/collecting/fakes-forgeries-and-reproductions)* in the art world: “**How [to forge](http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20140423-how-to-forge-a-masterpiece) a masterpiece**”

[OD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/forge) says:

> **forge** (verb) 3. Produce a fraudulent copy or imitation of (a document, signature, banknote, or work of art):
>   *the signature on the cheque was forged*

Finally, since no one else has suggested this, if the OP wishes to keep his original sentence then the terms, *perfect*, or *imitation* could both fit.

> The painting was a **perfect** copy of the original.
>   The painting was an (a perfect/poor) **imitation** of the original

Comment: There is the very useful expression *falso d'autore*, but I can't find an exact translation for it.

Comment: @Josh61 a **forger** is the closest equivalent. [Those prosecuting the conspirators are not the only ones to reveal inside tricks. In the past few months, **master forger** Wolfgang Beltracchi has given interviews to CBS, Channel 4 News and The Sunday Times – despite currently serving a six-year sentence for fraud.](http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20140423-how-to-forge-a-masterpiece)

Comment: Though the important difference is that *un falso d'autore* is a legal copy of a famous painting, certified and legally commerialized.

Comment: I would have to look it up but I believe that forgers can sell their copies in art galleries or private collectors, but obviously it is less remunerative than [passing it off](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+off+as) as a Modigliani for example.

Answer (score 1):

Replica.

From wikipedia:
"A replica is an exact reproduction, such as of a painting, as it was executed by the original artist or a copy or reproduction..."